# Setting unique properties per spooler in uwsgi

Tags: uwsgi

We have an application where we'd want to use uwsgi spoolers to queue up our long running tasks. There are 2 categories of such tasks:

1. Ones which are not memory intensive and usually finish within a minute
2. Ones which require a lot of memory, and also take 10s of minutes to finish.

We'd like to maintain 2 queues, and this is possible by adding 2 spoolers in the ini. However, we'd also like a different number of spooler processes to be spun up for the two queues. Spooler-1 could have a higher number of processes spun up (~10) due to its lower memory footprint, however, spooler-2 HAS to be limited to just 5 processes because we have limited memory. Is there a way to specify the number of processes per queue?

```
[uwsgi]
...
spooler=/tasks/spooler-1 ; Non-memory intensive
spooler=/tasks/spooler-2 ; Memory intensive
spooler-processes=10     ; This is applied across both spoolers. I'd like this to be a per-spooler config
...
```